# Flutter video_player initialization error when initializing multiple videos

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-s3, video-player, mux

### Problem I need help with

Assist with optimizing latency in its "Short-Video Feed" and solving intermittent performance bugs. A central feature of my app requires seamless plays 15 to 60 second clips when users use "swipe up" hand gestures similarly to TikTok and Instagram reels. Right now, I have performance bugs (intermittent) such as black screens, delayed loading screens, sometimes long loading, etc.

The bugs may be caused because Flutter is slower than Native iOS. However, our "Short-Video Feed" has lots of bugs whether I use a M3U8 (Mux), or whether I use a MP4 based approach with AWS S3.

If I use the Mux based approach with M3U8, "Short-Video Feed" there is a noticeable few milliseconds black screen for each short-video playback.

If I use the Amazon based approach with MP4, "Short-Video Feed" intermittently loads for a few seconds (sometimes minutes) when there is low bandwidth, and some videos get stuck even when a user returns to a location with faster bandwidth.

### Open issue on Flutter

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25558

### Approaches I have tried with no success:

- **Native Player**. I tried to use a native video player for Android/iOS, with MP4 and M3U8, but the UI was still very laggy (because of data transfer between Android/iOS and flutter latenices).
- **Flutter Player**. I tried to use a Flutter video player for Android/iOS, with MP4 and M3U8, but the UI shows a black screen with M3U8 & heavy loading for poor internet connections with MP4.

### Approaches I need help to try:

- Optimize M3U8 player to minimize the black screen issue.   or...
- Create MP4 chunks to optimize for poor reception areas (this is what I think TikTok Instagram Reels, and similar applications do based on what I can see).

Has anyone solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How about isolating whether these lags are due to network buffering or due to Flutter (or even a device hardware limitation such as memory or GPU)?
Perhaps use a few local MP4 files with identical frame rates and encoding parameters (both video and audio) and see whether the UI lag is reproducible upon swipe-up scrolling?

Comment: It is a Flutter issue. We logged everything and it shows that the Initialisation of the video takes time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try preloading video bro when you stand at index x
you can load next video x+1
and paus x-1 video
this way you can load video

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).